# How to remove *some* rows based on a given condition pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataset in Pandas and I want to remove some rows based on a given condition. I have a column in my dataset that is the number of comorbidities a participant has, the possible values are 0, 1, 2, 3. The dataset has roughly 1 million rows (and 30 other columns), with about 500k participants = 0 comorbidity, about 300K participants = 1 comorbidity, about 130K participants = 2 comorbidities, and about 75k participants = 3 comorbidities. I want to randomly drop groups of participants based on their comorbidities value, for example, drop 200k with 0 comorbidities, 100k with 1 comorbidity. I know if wanted to drop all participants with a given number of comorbidities, for example all participants with 0 comorbidities I could do the following:

dataframe = allpart, column name = CM

```
allpart.drop(allpart[allpart['CM'] == 0].index, inplace = True)
```

How could I change this so that it would randomly select 300k rows w/ 0 comorbidities? My data frame is not ordered in ascending order by that column so that rules out dropping a chunk of rows also I am not sure that would be random enough. I also want to mention that I will not be using this to draw any legitimate conclusions from this, it is solely just for my own interest.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to define how many rows you want to keep for each comorbidity and then `groupby` + `sample` to select a random subset of that size.

I added a small check in case you specify a number of rows that is larger than the number of unique rows that exist in your DataFrame for that `'CM'` group. In this case it just returns all rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(410112)

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(20), 'CM': np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4], 20)})
# Keys is comorbidity index, value is # of rows to keep 
d = {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 20, 4: 2}

l = []
for idx, gp in df.groupby('CM'):
    try:
        gp = gp.sample(n=d[idx], replace=False)
    # If try to subsample more people than exist, do nothing
    except ValueError:
        pass 
    l.append(gp)
    
df1 = pd.concat(l)
```

---

```
    id  CM
3    3   0
17  17   1
13  13   1
5    5   1
19  19   2
7    7   2
1    1   3
4    4   3
10  10   3
12  12   4
0    0   4
```

---

Another alternative which is similar but doesn't require reconstructing the entire DataFrame (so likely faster) would be to again specify a dictionary `d` of the number of rows to keep and use `sample(frac=1)` to shuffle the DataFrame, then `groupby` + `cumcount` to keep a random subset of rows.

```
# Keys is comorbidity index, value is # of rows to keep 
d = {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 20, 4: 2}

mask = df.sample(frac=1).groupby('CM', sort=False).cumcount().lt(df['CM'].map(d))
df1 = df[mask]
```

---

```
# Different subset of rows but still 1 row with CM0, 3 with CM1, ...

    id  CM
9    9   0
5    5   1
15  15   1
17  17   1
6    6   2
7    7   2
1    1   3
4    4   3
10  10   3
0    0   4
12  12   4
```